# kafka consumer group id does not work as expected

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am new people on apache Kafka. When I go through quick start instruction via http://kafka.apache.org/quickstart with latest version kafka_2.12-2.2.0.  I got a problem and can't figure it out by myself.

The issue is, on my laptop, I created 3 brokers to simulate cluster situation.

Each broker has its owned server property file.  I made below change for each server property file and leave other default value as what it is.

```
broker.id=1      (server2: broker.id=2;  server3: broker.id=3)

listeners=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092   (server2: 127.0.0.1:9023;  server3: 127.0.0.1:9004) 

log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs   (server2: /tmp/kafka-logs-2; server3: /tmp/kafka-logs-3)

num.partitions=3   (for all servers)

offsets.topic.replication.factor=3  (for all servers)
```

After I started ZK and those 3 brokers, I (can) create a topic 'TestTopic' with 3 partitions on any broker

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 3 --topic TestTopic
```

And then I use below command to start 3 consumers in the same group 'rickygroup'.

//consumer one

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --from-beginning --topic TestTopic —group.id rickygroup —group.name rickygroup
```

//consumer two

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9093 --from-beginning --topic TestTopic —group.id rickygroup —group.name rickygroup
```

//consumer three

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9094 --from-beginning --topic TestTopic —group.id rickygroup —group.name rickygroup
```

Now, I use another terminal to publish some messages on Topic 'TestTopic'. The issue is, all of the above 3 consumers will get all and exactly the same messages.  My understanding is 3 consumers should consume all messages indifference instead of the same.  Otherwise, the consumer group shows repeated consuming instead of balance consuming.

Is there any misunderstanding on consumer group concept by me? or anything I did wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console consumer uses `--group` (with two dashes), not `-group.id` and/or `-group.name`, which are not parsed options.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  It should be -- instead of - and it should be --group.  Unfortunately it doesn't raise exception, so I didn't check the command and wasted some time yesterday.  Thank you.